# Error during Web application deploy using windows installer

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, web-deployment, web-setup-project

I have made the Web application setup package using windows installer, This package hosts application in IIS and Install Database on sql server. It was working fine previously but suddenly i am getting following error and database not deploying on Sql server but IIS Deployment was successful.
I am getting following error in Log File

> 20.01.2017 13:41:53 System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   File name: 'Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
>      at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError)
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.GetStatements(String query, ExecutionTypes executionType, Int32& statementsToReverse)
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType)
>      at UpdatingWebconfig.Installer1.ExecuteSqlsecond(String strScript, String serverName, String dbName, String userName, String password)
>   WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
>   To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
>   Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
>   To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a possible solution:

> might be the SQL Server is 32bit and the Windows is 64bit.
>
> Because of your Windows is 64bit, when the 64bit application started,
>   it will call the assembly of 64bit, but the SQL Server Installation is
>   32bit and the 64bit assembly might be not included, so you should make
>   sure that you have both Microsoft.SQLServer.BatchParser of 32bit and
>   64bit. You could confirm this by following steps:
>
> 1. Open  C:\Windows\assembly
> 2. Find Microsoft.SQLServer.BatchParser, there should be two.
> 3. Right-click on them, make sure that one of them is AMD64 and another is X86.
>
> If you couldn’t find the Microsoft.SQLServer.BatchParser of 64bit,
>   please download and install Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Shared
>   Management Objects, because of the Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser
>   assembly is included in Microsoft SQL Server SMO.

reference: [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4d682289-9e06-4dd3-aff3-d08ad437896d/file-or-assembly-microsoftsqlserverbatchparser-error?forum=sqldatabaseengine)

Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. There are four Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser version 10 and 12 for x86 and Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser for version 12 and 11 of amd64

Comment: you need version 11 (for the error message) version 11 is SQLServer 2012. 
What version of SQLServer you have?  

try install two MSI for SQL 2012 in same order as later one is depended.

1. SharedManagementObjects.msi  
2. SQLSysClrTypes.msi

You can download it from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35580)

Comment: I have sql server 2014 when i install from you provided link it says higher version is alrady installed uninstall it first.

Comment: When i am uninstall it it shows access denied error and yes error saying for version 11 but it is not allowing me to install version 11

Comment: you need x86 version 11 file. are you installing "ENU\x86\SharedManagementObjects.msi" and "ENU\x86\SQLSysClrTypes.msi" from the last link?
(remember run it in Administrator mode)

Comment: SQLSysClrTypes.msi this installed successfuly but when installing this SharedManagementObjects.msi it gives error "filed because higher version is already installed first uninstall that and try again"

Comment: look this [link](http://126kr.com/article/8esu5x0lf1q). he use [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42295) version.

Comment: Nothing is working. System which have version 11 of BatchParser working fine but unfortunately in my client system BatchParser v11 not there.